# 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, ls

'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I get this error when I try to glance at the files of my folder.

- cmd opened regularly(not as an admin).
- I've recently downloaded anaconda for python.During the installation process, there was a time when I allowed to add a PATH which was not recommended.
  'ls' used to work well be

  Here are the paths

  [image]

Comment: Are you sure you are not supposed to be using 'dir' since it is windows?

Comment: You can use it in other terminal programs like GitBash but it is not shipped with windows.

Comment: `dir` on windows is similar to `ls.` Do `dir/?` for various options. You could also install 3rd party tools to allow you to run unix commands on windows. Try [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html)

Comment: `ls` also might work on some ftp servers if they have a linux based back. That ftp being used from cmd

Comment: You can install the Microsoft `Windows Subsystem for Linux`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the `ls` command is for Linux, not Windows (I'm assuming you're using Windows as you referred to `cmd`, which is the command line for the Windows OS).

You should use `dir` instead, which is the Windows equivalent of `ls`.

**Edit (since this post seems to be getting so many views :) ):**

You can't use `ls` on `cmd` as it's not shipped with `Windows`, but you *can* use it on other terminal programs (such as GitBash). Note, `ls` might work on some `FTP` servers if the servers are `linux` based and the `FTP` is being used from `cmd`.

`dir` on `Windows` is similar to `ls`. To find out the various options available, just do `dir/?`.

If you really want to use `ls`, you could install 3rd party tools to allow you to run `unix` commands on `Windows`. Such a program is `Microsoft Windows Subsystem for Linux` ([link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)).

Comment: You can use `ls`  in powershell

Comment: @CopyrightC sick

Comment: use "dir/adh" command to see the hidden files too

Answer (score 45):

We can use `ls` and many other Linux commands in **Windows cmd**. Just follow these steps.

Steps:

1) Install Git in your computer - https://git-scm.com/downloads.

2) After installing Git, go to the folder in which Git is installed.
   Mostly it will be in `C drive` and then `Program Files` Folder.

3) In `Program Files` folder, you will find the folder named `Git`, find the `bin` folder 
   which is inside `usr` folder in the Git folder.

In my case, the location for bin folder was - `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

4) Add this location (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`) in path variable, in **system 
   environment variables**.

5) You are done. Restart cmd and try to run `ls` and other Linux commands.

Answer (score 4):

you can use dir instead of ls in cmd
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Unix shell commands on Windows, you can use Windows Powershell, which includes both Windows and Unix commands as aliases. You can find more info on it in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/using-familiar-command-names?view=powershell-6).

> PowerShell supports aliases to refer to commands by alternate names.
>   Aliasing allows users with experience in other shells to use common
>   command names that they already know for similar operations in
>   PowerShell.
>
> The PowerShell equivalents may not produce identical results. However,
>   the results are close enough that users can do work without knowing
>   the PowerShell command name.

Comment: This is right. I tried Powershell and `ls` command works in it. But it is not recognized in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

when you use windows as operating system you should write `dir`
and you will find all folders including empty folders and their data bytes storage

and you can use `git ls-files` to show all folders but not including hidden folders

Answer (score 1):

for windows use "ls" command in windows powershell, and if you are in command prompt the use "dir" command instead of "ls" it is almost equivalent

Comment: For inline code usages you can use `code` syntaxis.
For blocks of code you can use expanded code syntaxis like below
```
example of code
```

If you want to target the specific language, it's also possible

```php
$var = 1;
```

It's more visible in answers

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot run the `ls` command is because it does not exist on windows. The windows equivalent is the `dir` command, however it does not work the same way. The solution, [Winls](https://github.com/mathstar13/winls). It is

> The `ls` command, written for windows.

According the the `Winls` github.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error because i was using command prompt to access my files.

how did i solve it...

i opened my folder with vscode, and used bash from the terminal...the "ls" command worked as it should from bash.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` command is a Unix/Linux command that is not recognized by Windows Command Prompt. Instead, you can use the `dir` command in Command Prompt to list the files and directories in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dir instead of ls to see all the files and folders present and use dir /a instead of ls -a to see all the hidden folders.