# why command are not recognized by the command prompt?

Tags: cmd

I have tried several times to type the command 'ls' at the command prompt of Windows 10 but it shows me that the command is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file.

Comment: In windows, that command is `dir`.

Comment: If you change the Command Prompt window to a Windows PowerShell window, you can use the `ls` command there. _Technically it isn't a command but an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, (which also has the aliases `dir` and `gci` too)!_ To learn all about that 'command' whilst you're there, grab a large coffeee, then type `help ls -full`, and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032646/ls-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b)

Answer (score 0):

The "is" command is for Linux, not for Windows, and like Kraigolas said, the Windows OS command is "dir". Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` command is for linux and it's equivalent for windows command prompt is `dir`. But if you are more of a linux user then you can try using power-shell on windows where `ls` command works just like the way it works in linux. Power-shell is like a hybrid between windows command prompt and linux terminal.